# i want python to open a wesite and then refresh it or reopen it a sertain amount of times

Tags: python, loops, input, browser

here is what i have so far:

```
loop = 1
print ("Copy your Youtube link")
Website = input (">>>")
print ("How manmy views would you like to get?")
Views = input (">>>")
print (Website)
print (Views)

import time
import webbrowser
Websites = webbrowser.open(Website) THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE WEBSITE TO REFRESH OR OPEN MORE. THE (VIEWS) amount
print ("There you go")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will let you achieve your objectives. The program will also allow the user to control the amount of pages opening at one time as well as the the delay in closing them. This allows for differences in computer specs.

```
import os
import time
import webbrowser

cycles=int(input("Please input the number of cycles you want to run"))
num=int(input("Please input the number of pages you want to open in each cycle"))
delay=int(input("Please input the time delay for restarting the cycle"))
website = input("Please input your web address")

hits=cycles*num
print("You will access " +website+ " " , hits, " times")

for i in range(cycles):
    for i in range(num):
        webbrowser.open(website)
    time.sleep(delay)
    os.system("tskill /A iexplore")
    os.system("tskill /A Chrome")
```

Answer (score 2):

[Use a loop](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) to perform actions repeatedly. The loop can either repeat *n* times (`for` loop with `xrange()`), step over elements in a list (`for item in list:`) or repeat until some condition is satisfied (`while condition_is_true:`).

Be aware that calling `webbrowser.open()` repeatedly may not be a good idea. (Hint: What happens when you open a thousand browser windows all at the same time?)

---

If the *intent* of this script is to inflate the view count of a YouTube video (therefore propelling you to stardom), be aware that this will not work. YouTube almost certainly deduplicates views from the same computer, so that loading a video 1000 times on the same computer will not increase the view count by 1000. Instead, the view count will increase by 1.

Additionally, repeatedly hitting their site with an automated bot for the purpose of inflating page views is both impolite and almost certainly against their terms of service.

Also, I'm being nitpicky, but please make some effort to spellcheck your English. 'i' should be 'I', and 'sertain' should be 'certain'.

Comment: Spellchecking is a courtesy to the people who are going to the effort of reading and answering your question. It shows that you put effort into the asking of your question. English being your third language is no barrier to using the spellchecker that is almost certainly built into your web browser. If I was asking questions in German, I would be doubly certain to use a German spellchecker to make sure my spelling was correct.

Comment: Well, i am sorry Li-aung Yip. That is not a very Australian name is it, so i am assuming that English is not your first language either. I am sorry, i joined this Website to get an answer for my lack of programming knowledge not for an English lesson, but thanks for trying to educate me.

Comment: @VincentdeVries: Additionally, YouTube [does de-duplicate page views from the same computer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16906/youtube-view-count-how-does-it-work). Remember that YouTube sells advertising based on the number of views, so far smarter people than you or I have already tried to game the system. YouTube has developed defences against this and I would be extremely surprised if you could get a significant number ( > 1000 ) of page views by repeatedly refreshing the page.

Comment: @VincentdeVries: It is unwise to assume someone's nationality based on their name or picture.

Comment: I got 200 so far from refreshing the page 200 times, it works. And "smarter people" than me?! very good to know how smart you are.

Comment: Try that for 100,000 views. From the internet: "YouTube has sophisticated technology to count views consistently. **If this technology detects that there has been an attempt to inflate a video’s view count artificially,** that video’s view count will be frozen, according to YouTube guidelines. During this time the video is still available and the all-important view count will continue, only it will not appear until the video and the issue has been adjudicated."

Comment: i will only do it for 20 the max anyway. I am just trying to get a few more Views, thats all ;P

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to achieve however to have it open the website you defined a set number of times you could try:

```
num = 3
website = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

for i in xrange(0,num):
    webbrowser.open(website)
```

Comment: `xrange()` is preferred over `range`, otherwise spot-on.

Comment: i am trying to make a simple program that opens a sertain website a sertain amout of times. like you type "google" and 5 and it will open google 5 times :D

Comment: @VincentdeVries then my suggestion should do the trick. You would just need to get an input for the num and website values as per your intial example. Also, as Li-aung noted you may encounter some serious problems if you try to open 1,000 browser windows so you might want to check the value that has been entered before beginning your loop.

Comment: @timc thanks mate. i will probably limit the amount to 20 or something. but just a question, is there a way to automate refreshing of a website?

Comment: @VincentdeVries: See the [Selenium browser automation framework](http://seleniumhq.org/) which has Python bindings.

Comment: @VincentdeVries no worries. If an answer helped address your question then you should accept it to help other users who may have a similar issue. As Li-aung mentioned the Selenium framework is your best bet for browser automation.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one in spyder but it not execute, when i click on stop then its open google chrome with exit search not link search : import os import time import webbrowser

cycles=12 num=3 delay=0.10 chromedir = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s' website = input("http:\youtu.be/RsWCo_xGXxY") hits=cycles*num print("You will access " +website+ " " , hits, " times")

for i in range(cycles): for i in range(0,num): webbrowser.get(chromedir).open(website) time.sleep(delay) os.system("tskill /A iexplore") os.system("tskill /A Chrome")